# Two containers or two separate machines?

Tags: linux, docker

At the moment I have one dedicated server on one container - a scraper for data,
on the second container - database, and frontend for browsing these data.

Next month we must migrate to a new machine, and I think that it is better will be two separate machines with docker, when is each machine running only one container, what are you guys thinking about it?

Answer (score 0):

We would need more informations about your use case.

Do you need high availability ?
Do you care about your data ?
If your only server dies, is it an issue ?
If one of both server, is it an issue ?

What do you want to acheive here ?

Comment: I afriad that one container can affects on another container, when CPU load from one container up etc, do you agree with me?

Comment: Ha ! So what you want is to ''leach'' you containers. You can limit RAM and CPU consumption as well as disks. Here is the doc for RAM and CPU: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/.      I suggest you also monitor the ressources usage with a monitoring system or metrics.  There should no or velly little impact from one container to another. This is one of the existing reasons of containers.